# How to get the TypeScript compiler to not emit the directory structure

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, typescript, build, tsc

in my current TypeScript project I have the following file structure:

```
project
├─app
│ └─index.html
├─test
└─src
  ├─app
  │ ├─tsconfig.json
  │ └─app.ts
  ├─lib
  │ └─lib.ts
  └─test
    ├─tsconfig.json
    └─test.ts
```

What I would like to achieve is that when compiling this project for `app` and `test` that the resulting file structure looks like this:

```
project
├─app
│ ├─index.html
│ └─app.js
├─test
│ ├─lib
│ │ └─lib.js
│ └─test.js
└─src
  └─...
```

or this:

```
project
├─app
│ ├─index.html
│ └─app.js
├─test
│ ├─lib.js
│ └─test.js
└─src
  └─...
```

I have a library that sits in the lib directory. It is used by the app.ts which is then used on the web page. The tests sit inside the test directory. What I actually get is:

```
project
├─app
│ ├─index.html
│ └─app.js
├─test
│ ├─lib
│ │ └─lib.js
│ └─test
│   └─test.js
└─src
  └─...
```

Notice the extra `test`-directory.

The `src/test/tsconfig.json`-file looks like this:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2016",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2016"
        ],
        "outDir": "../../test",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "module": "commonjs"
    },
    "files": [
        "test.ts"
    ]
}
```

As I want to execute those tests on my machine using node.js I had to choose `commonjs` as module system. This does not merge all the TypeScript modules like the `amd`-module system does. So as far as I understand it `tsc` searches for the first common parent directory of all involved modules and makes that the base directory for the output. That common directory would be `src` that is why there is an extra level of directories in the output directory.

So my question is:
**How can I tell the TypeScript compiler to use `src/test` as root directory for the output, so that `test.js` is put into `test/test.js` and not in `test/test/test.js`?**

Setting `"rootDir": "./"` does not work as the compiler will output an error:

```
error TS6059: File '[...]/lib/lib.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '[...]/src/test/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```